# How to wait until file is uploaded before getting firebase storage URL? -- React --

Tags: reactjs, async-await, firebase-storage

I'm currently learning React and am having some trouble after uploading a photo to firebase storage. I am able to upload the file, but when I go to retrieve and update my state with `.getDownloadURL()`, it only displays the default blank string. I know this is because the `.getDownloadURL()` call is occurring before the file is totally uploaded. I've messed around with async/await and can't seem to figure out how to wait until the file has been uploaded. Here is my code so far:

```js
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    await onFileSubmit()

    console.log(desc, title, price, picURL, inventory)
    // TODO: Add item entry to firebase
}

const onFileSubmit = async () => {
    if(pic == null)
        return;

    // add file to firebase storage
    const imageRef = projectStorage.ref(`/${pic.name}`)
    await imageRef.put(pic)

    // get the url for the image and update state
    setPicURL(await imageRef.getDownloadURL().toString())

    console.log(picURL)
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
uploadBytes(storageRef, image).then((snapshot) => {
          getDownloadURL(storageRef).then((url) => {
            addDoc(collection(db, "images"), {
              url: url,
              name: image.name,
              imId: imId,
              createdAt: new Date(),
            })
              .then((docRef) => {
                console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
              });
          });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).